# ffmpeg decoding on a encoded stream (coming as buffer)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, decoding, encoder, hevc

I am getting enocded data in a uin8_t* buffer with the buffer size, can I use ffmpeg decoder to decode this data ?

If so How can I convert uint8_t* encoded_data to the AvPacket required by ffmpeg?
do I need to initialize any metadata parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

```
AVPacket *pkt = av_packet_alloc();
av_new_packet(pkt, size);
memcpy(pkt->data, data, size);
..
av_packet_free(&pkt);
```

And in ".." would then be your packet handler, typically calls to `avcodec_send_packet()` and `avcodec_receive_frame()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. can you please explain if I need to fill any parameters in av codec context ? I am trying to use decode_video.c example in ffmpeg dir, It uses av_parse_parse2() when I am using that application I am getting these errorrs: [hevc @ 0x560349d165c0] Could not find ref with POC 27 [hevc @ 0x560349d165c0] Could not find ref with POC 9
[hevc @ 0x560349d165c0] Invalid number of merging MVP candidates: 6.
[hevc @ 0x560349d165c0] Error parsing NAL unit #0.[hevc @ 0x560349d165c0] Could not find ref with POC 25Too many refs in a short term RPS.

Comment: Ah, it's HEVC. This is more complicated. You need to figure out the encoding (startcode-prefixed or not) and convert if needed. Look into BSFs (bitstream filters) like hevc_mp4toannexb.